# Is this database design ok?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am developing a mvc app for a carpet company. A carpet's price will depend upon color combinations and size. So to model this scenario i am using 2 tables.
1.Carpets.
2.CarpetVarients.(For various color and size combinations).

In CarpetVarients table i am thinking about creating columns "Colors", "Size" and "Price" (along other columns). Colors column will store comma delimited colors(like Cream,Red,).

Will this design work? or should i make every combination a different carpet.

Comment: What sort of query would you use for the colors column?

Comment: Good point. Will you ever want to know 'tell me all the carpets that have red in the colour'? If not, then colour is fine in a description field. If colour needs to be queried individually you should put it in its own lookup table

Comment: I have not started programming yet, but feeling entity sql with .Where(c => c.Colors.Contains("red")) may work with a join of 2 tables.

Comment: @Nick, yes its required "tell me all the carpets that have red in the color?".

Comment: @Nick, so you are suggesting tables like CarpetColors, CarpetSizes and CarpetColorSizePrices along with Carpets table???, or can you suggest a better design???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, storing things as delimited strings is not a good idea (unless you are talking about a carpet that has multiple colours in which case things might be different). Better to have a row for each colour/size combination.

Maybe it would be better to think of what you call `Carpet` as a `Style` and then the `Carpet` table can have `Style`, `Colour` and `Size`.

e.g.

```
Style
StyleID     StyleName   Description
1           'Modern'    'Striped'
2           'Rustic'    'Checks'

Carpet
CarpetID  StyleID  Colour           Size    Price
1         1        'Red-Green'      'Small' '£'
2         1        'Orange-Teal'    'Large' '£££'
3         2        'Violet-Magenta' 'Large' '£££££'
```

e.g. Design to answer "Tell me all the carpets that have xxx as a colour."

```
…
Carpet
CarpetID  StyleID  Size    Price
1         1        'Small' '$'
2         1        'Large' '$$$'
3         2        'Large' '$$$$$'

Colour
ColourID ColourName RGB
1        Red        255, 0, 0
2        Green      0, 255, 0

CarpetColour
CarpetID ColourID
1        1
1        2
2        3
2        4
...
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?. Carpet can have multiple colors. Its like a shirt, but different colors will have different price. Say blue-black carpet1 of size x will be priced y, and green-black carpet1 of size x will be priced z.

Comment: @rahul example added, the essence is not putting different *options* for colours on the same row, just all the colours in a combination.

Comment: Thank you, it looks more viable. But i am little skeptic that questions like  'tell me all the carpets that have red in the color'? can be answered accurately. Is there a better design possible?

Comment: @rahul Well, if you expect that question, then you would *definitely* not want to store multiple colours in the same field. Store them in a related table as shown in updated sample.

Comment: Thanks a-ton :|) . This is much better. I think i should do the same for price also?. What do you suggest?, will it do any good for price range search?

Comment: Each `Carpet` only has a fixed number of prices (one) so no need to move to another table. If you expect lots of searches by price then that field might be a good field to index, but at this stage that would probably be premature optimisation, and designing the right index would be the subject of another question.

Answer (score 0):

You should create tables as follows:

```
Carpet
CarpetID (PK), CarpetName, Description
   1               abc      green-yellow 2*3

CarpetVarient
StyleID (FK), Color, Size, Price
   1           green  2     100
   1           yellow 3     100
```

So a carpet can be of multiple styles and total `price` of a carpet would be sum of Price based upon `StyleId`. Ex.The carpet named **abc** would be of total 200

Comment: Company will decide price, there is no fixed criteria for price. Carpet can have color combinations, and different color combinations will have different price. Its like blue-black carpet1 of size x will be priced y, and green-black carpet1 of size x will be priced z.

Comment: Either price could be style based or whole? If whole then we can move price filed to main table. Second table works fine for style combinations

Comment: Price depends on 2 attributes colors(or single color) and size. But i am not able to comprehend your model. Especially the "Description" column. 2*3 is ???

Comment: description is anything you can write for future reference, its like a notes

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like

```
Carpet:
CarpetId   Carpet_PartNumber  Color   Size   parentID  Price
1                AB12          NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2                AB23          Green   12inch   1      100
```

This way you can have every carpet as a Individual product.
Note(for color and size you can use a LOOKUP Table)